# Exporting Blocks from Drupal 6 to 7

Tags: 6, blocks, importing-exporting

Can anyone tell me the best way to export blocks from Drupal 6 to 7?

Boxes? Features? A Straight field for filed export?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are straight up Blocks with body content (not View blocks or other contrib generated blocks), I would create a module that scripts and creates them on install. If you have many blocks, do them in small batches (breaking them up across update_n hooks).

That way you can also test them in small batches and get it right. Once up, you can disable the module and remove it.

See:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/72946/57
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1709954#comment-8592077